# Software comparison: off-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

Sometimes I need to know how 2 or more applications compare with regards to a specific feature / criterion:

e.g.

- How does the speech recognition accuracy compare between Dragon NaturallySpeaking's and CMU Sphinx?
- How much faster is copying files though TeraCopy vs. Windows 7 native copy function?

I believe it is but just to confirm is that off-topic? If so is there some SE where I can ask such questions?

Comment: See also: [Is tool x versus tool y a fair question?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/69/60)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I agree with your assumptions: questions like "How do X and Y compare" is off topic on SR. But as usual, there might be a "gray zone".

Taking e.g. your second example about the file copiers, you could put it like this:

> I need a really fast copy tool, working natively on Windows 7. It must be capable of:
>
> - copying large and small files alike
> - working across drive boundaries
> - [ put additional requirements here ]
>
> I already know about *TeraCopy* and Windows' built-in copy function (not sure how they compare in speed and resource usage, though) [ ... ]

Basically the same thing, but fully fitting our site as it meets all criteria – while it hides your "secret" question between the lines. Bonus for you: an answer might turn up naming a "SuperCopy" tool which fits your requirements even better :)